# Sub-query and join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to launch a sub select with a join but I have a problem on the return

```
SELECT * FROM user, follow
WHERE user.id IN ( SELECT follow FROM referent_follow WHERE referent=3 )
```

In the above case the return is good but I have in addition all my table follow that I didn't want

```
SELECT * FROM user, follow
WHERE follow.user_id IN ( SELECT follow FROM referent_follow WHERE referent=3 )
```

In the above case the return is good but I have in addition all my table user that I didn't want

Query that works less badly is the first one but I have content of follow in my result too.

Comment: can you provide sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query result a cartesian product from both tables: `user` and `follow`. You need to supply a condition that will join and filter out connected records.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*, b.* 
FROM    user a
        INNER JOIN follow b
            ON a.ID = b.user_id 
        INNER JOIN referent_follow c
            ON a.ID = c.follow
WHERE   c.referent = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I undersant better

Answer (score 1):

`FROM A,B` means a cross-join of A and B. So every row in A is matched to every row B
(so `totalRows = rowCount(A)*rowCount(B)`).

Using an `(INNER) JOIN` should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
JOIN follow ON user.id = follow.user_id
  AND user.id IN ( SELECT follow FROM referent_follow WHERE referent=3 )
```

Using `JOIN` rather than `IN` would be advised, since it generally results in better performance:

```
SELECT user.*, follow.*
FROM user
JOIN follow ON user.id = follow.user_id
JOIN referent_follow ON user.id = referent_follow.follow
WHERE referent=3
```

You may also need a `DISTINCT` as JW suggested.